# How get input attributes in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I use jquery autocomplete.

And I want add to source URL attribute from this input. How?

This code don't work:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: "/service/autocomplete/"+$(this).data('source'),
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log( ui.item );

}
```

Comment: by source url you mean this `"/service/autocomplete/"+$(this).data('source')`?

Comment: Your going to have to be a bit more descriptive than that. `And I want add to source URL attribute from this input. How?` really isn't giving us much to go on. What do you mean you want to add to it? do you mean you want to dynamically change it on a per need basis? what exactly outside of the `autocomplete` stock functions are you attempting to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you have it placed `this` will not mean the element the plugin is being instantiated on. If you need this behaviour you need to create each instance in a loop so that you can get access to the attributes on each specific matched element:

```
$('input.autocomplete').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var source = "/service/autocomplete/" + $el.data('source');

    $el.autocomplete({
        source: source,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log( ui.item );    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes,, i love this! :D